# How do I tell my parents that my wife and I are expecting a child?

Tags: pregnancy, parents

My wife is pregnant with our first child, and we want to find a unique and fun way to tell our parents.

Comment: Congratulations. My sister phoned my Mum on Mother's day, and casually wished her a "Happy _Grandmother's_ Day". It took her a little while to work it out, but when she did... :-)

Comment: Me: *Hey Mom, do you have anything planned for February yet?* Mom (confused): *Uhm, no, not really, it's still quite far in the future, isn't it?* Me (smug): *Yes, about nine months...* Mom: *???* (Then the penny drops, and she suddenly needs a kleenex)

Comment: This might get closed as there isn't really a 'best' way to answer this, but it's a fun question.

Comment: Ask them to answer this question.

Comment: I know that this is an old question but it seems completely out of place for a SE site. This is not a chat board. You have no real "problem" to solve, you're just looking for ideas and idea generation is not really within scope of any SE site.

Answer (score 11):

In this answer, I am assuming this pregnancy will be seen as good news by your parents.

My sister announced her pregnancy at Christmas Time by simply adding a stocking to the mantel that said "baby (last name)" and then the due date.  When we all got up in the morning, there it was hanging there with a few of the baby items they'd already purchased in preparation.

My Husband and I wrapped up "away" packages with things like a bib, a few diapers and the like as a "gift" to each set of parents for use when we and the baby visited.  The packages contained a note that said, "for when I visit my grandparents.  Love, baby (last name)"

Both ways seemed like they were really fun for my parents (although in both cases they had their guesses anyway - we're pretty close).  The gift with the baby stuff in it confused my in-laws.

Congratulations!

Comment: That is awesome!

Answer (score 6):

A "grandma/grandpa" picture frame with a sonogram picture in it.

Comment: We did this for my mother-in-law. She loved it.

Answer (score 6):

You can e. g. invite the grandparents for afternoon tee
and then put **place cards** with "Grandpa John", "Grandma Hilary", .... on the desk.

Comment: great suggestion, simple and attainable..

Comment: @AylsBillones: if you like it, you can upvote it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Some of my favourite suggestions I've seen:

- Send pictures of the wife barefoot in the kitchen. It's subtle enough that it might require some prodding to get the hint
- Since it's the Christmas season, get some Christmas cards targeted as being from a grandchild to grandparents (this works especially well for if it's near a birthday or Mother's/Father's Day as well)

Answer (score 4):

We mailed my Mom the pregnancy test, nothing else in the envelope, just the positive pregnancy test.

The funny thing is that she didn't get it.  She said, "What on earth would I do with a pregnancy test.  I'm past menopause."

Comment: The results bar can fade away over time.

Comment: LOL! That's... Awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions:

- What I did, inspired in a proffesional photographer's idea (I can't find it right now, but it's on internet): I grabbed my Reflex camera and started shooting photos in burst mode while my couple told them the new. The changes in their faces from stranged/worried to ultra happines is priceless.

  I did it with all our relatives and friends. Now I'm making an album with the before/after pictures, so when my kid will grow up will see how happy got the people who are important for him/her when they first knew of her/him.
- My sibling gave the news on Christmas season: hanged the [pregnancy test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregnancy_test) from the christmas tree with a big red bow (so it would be noticeable).

  On Christmas day, when all the family came to the house, "saw" the news.

Comment: No thank you to hanging the pregnancy test from the Christmas tree. You have to pee on those. Ew.

Comment: @NateCook You 1st remove the cap. 2nd pee on the point (or put it in a container with urine). 3rd put the cap back on.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a holiday or special occasion, and then after dinner time, you can give them the ultrasound result, placed on a baby stuff.  They could easily guess that. :) Congratulations!